# Listen for creation of an element and fire an event when it appears on the page in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to have a Chrome extension listen for the appearance of a yet-to-be-created element?

Say the user clicks a button and the click event creates an element `<div id='myDiv'>My Div</div>` and adds it to the page/DOM. Is it possible to set a listener that will automatically fire an event when that element appears?

Or do I have to resort to polling the page and checking for this element every X amount of milliseconds?

jQuery and other libraries are not an option for me btw.

Comment: Why not keep track of the button clicks? Or will it load through other means?

Comment: It is actually being created with an AJAX callback but I just phrased it in the most straightforward way for the sake of example. So I have to listen for the creation/appearance of the element.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page

... In any case it looks like the most elegant solution is now deprecated (DOM Mutation Events), but there is a hacky solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997826/alternative-to-domnodeinserted

Comment: @Cecchi This isn't *quite* a duplicate, since this question specificallly excludes jQuery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new [DOM4 MutationObserver](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) can do this.  I don't think it's widely supported yet, but luckily enough for you, it is supported in Chrome, as `WebKitMutationObserver`.

Modified from the linked tutorial page, this listens for mutations everywhere on the page:

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            if(mutation.addedNodes[i].id == "myDiv") {
                // target node added, respond now...
            }
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(document, { subtree: true });
```

If you can narrow your listening in `observer.observe` to a more specific element than `document`, that would give you some performance gain.

Comment: Is there a legacy implementation?

Comment: @zladuric Perhaps you might be interested in [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use external libraries. setInterval it will have to remain.

Comment: @zladuric Despite the question title, the accepted answer to that question doesn't use jQuery. It uses [DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), which are plain old JS.

Comment: This works, but when I use it (in Chrome, for listening to the birth of an element in Gmail), I get an error that says the options object must set at least one of 'attributes', 'characterData', or 'childList' to true. Which is indeed what you need to do to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/), it wraps the [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) api. Usage:

```
document.arrive(".test-elem", function() {
    // 'this' refers to the newly created element
    var newElem = this;
});
```