# How to fire a event when a div got removed and added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following type of code

```
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="child-div">
    <!--content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The child div comes from third party service it will get attached or removed dynamically. How to fire a javascript event during attaching the are removing the div

Comment: [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver): _provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification._

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Have a loop - Every x milliseconds, check to see if `child-div` exists / does not exists
2. Use the [DOM4 MutationObserver](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) - More info on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Note: <strike>This is only currently supported in Google Chrome</strike> [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Related question with answer about the DOM4 MutationObserver:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141879/5620297

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery use 
[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/),

in the function or code you attach the child div, after attaching the child div put

```
$("div#parent-div").trigger("child_div_attached");
```

in the function or code you remove the child div, after removing the child div put

```
$("div#parent-div").trigger("child_div_removed");
```

then you can add event listener to parent div like,

```
$("div#parent-div").on("child_div_attached", function() {
  //what to do after child div attached
});

$("div#parent-div").on("child_div_removed", function() {
  //what to do after child div removed
});
```