# TinyMCE event for HTML tag added

Tags: tinymce

Is there any way to bind to an event that is fired when a new HTML tag is added to the editor? Basically, I'd like to be able to add a special token to the beginning of all `<p>` tags and am thinking this is probably the best way to do it, but also open to other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for a DOMNodeInserted event.
But for further use it is advised not to use mutation observer events anymore.
For this have alook at this SO thread: [Alternative to DOMNodeInserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997826/alternative-to-domnodeinserted)