# Any implementation of Microsoft Selector-based Mutation Events?

Tags: html

Do any projects exist that implement the follow proposal?

http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/wiki/Selector-based_Mutation_Events

Comment: You could try mutation observers. Although they will listen to every added element, they have much better performance than mutation events. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu0tvced/1/)

Comment: As stated in the original question: `The DOM I'm modifying however is quite complex, so I don't want to listen to *every* node that's added for performance reasons.` 
 
But thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a better way that allows you to listen for any selector with actual events, vs dirty checking, mutation listening, and other non-performant ideas: https://github.com/csuwildcat/SelectorListener (it was also used as the basis of this highly rated solution: [Alternative to DOMNodeInserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997826/alternative-to-domnodeinserted/10343915#10343915))

Here are a few examples:

```
// Listening for attribute value matches? Child's play.
document.addSelectorListener('.foo[bar="boom"]', function(){ ... });

// Matching elements on hashchange can be annoying, let's make it stupid simple
document.addSelectorListener('*:target', function(event){
  alert('The hash-targeted element is:' + event.target);
});

// How about a more performant way to listen for custom tooltip nodes document wide?
document.addSelectorListener('.tooltip:hover', function(){ ... });


/*** Now that we have the new CSS 4 Selector spec, let's see what we can do: ***/

// Working with HTML5 sliders just got even easier
document.querySelector('#RandomForm').addSelectorListener('slider:out-of-range', function(){
  alert('Your slider value is now out of range! Oh noes!');
```