# Call JS on when particular div is loaded in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call some JS function when particular div with class is loaded in my Rails 4 app.

```html
<div class="myClass">
  hello world
</div
```

How to call some js code only when this div is loaded.

Comment: use jquery to check if div with that class exist using lenght() and then call a method..

Comment: Define loaded: injected into the page using ajax, or run a particular piece of  js when it is present on the page? If using ajax: how do you inject the html?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, it is relevant to rails

There can be two approach:

1: write a JS code below your html DIV

```
<div class="myClass">
  hello world
</div
<script type="text/javascript">
yourfuncion();
</script>
```

2: call a function when document is ready, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    yourfuncion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to `DOMNodeInserted` to check when a certain element has been loaded.

Example:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(event){
  if($(event).hasClass("myClass")){
    // do something
  }
});
```

Use with caution if your page is large as this is known to cause performance concerns. 
[Alternative to DOMNodeInserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997826/alternative-to-domnodeinserted)

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is check is the div is loaded every few seconds until it's loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkDiv();
});

function checkDiv () {
  if($('#myDiv').is(':visible'))){ 
    // what you whant
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkDiv, 50); //wait and try again. 
  }
}
```

I hope it's helps.

Comment: Given you've put it in a `document.ready();` surely it will always have been loaded in the first time that runs?

Comment: Was my mistake. if the div is not visible it's going to wait 50ms and then execute again until it's loaded. @japed