# How do I apply jquery plugin to newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a third party function that I use.  To use ii I just run:

```
$('.myElements').thirdPartyFunction(options);
```

It works fine.  However if I dynamically add an element with class `.myElements`, how can I have it run the thirdPartyFunction on that that element?

Comment: `$('.otherElements').addClass('myElements').thirdPartyFunction(options);` I don't believe there are shortcuts

Comment: That is manually running it.  How do I listen if elements have been added with that class and then run the function.

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. You have to track when elements with that class have been added and run the third party function on it again. You could look into using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to help with that, but it might be more trouble than it's worth, depending on the size of your code base.

Comment: What function add the new element? Is a function created by you? If yes, it is the right place to run your `thirdPartyFunction`

Comment: Unfortunately this is a chrome extension I'm writing that runs on a third party site.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about performance you can use DOMNodeInserted

```
$(document).bind("DOMNodeInserted"), function(event){
      $(event.target).find(".myElements").addBack(".myElements").thirdPartyFunction();
}
```

Though it is not very performant, so you may wish to look at something else.

Other options:  [Alternative to DOMNodeInserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997826/alternative-to-domnodeinserted)